# Get mapping value in hardhat

Tags: solidity, mapping, ethers.js, hardhat, typescript

I have a mapping in my contract

```
mapping (uint256 => uint256) totalBoostedPercent;
```

I am using hardhat and typechain to generate type from my contract. In my test file.ts, I tried to access the value of mapping

```
await contract.totalBoostedPercent(0)
Property 'totalBoostedPercent' does not exist on type 'Contract'.
```

I tried another

```
await (contract as any).totalBoostedPercent(0)
TypeError: contract.totalBoostedPercent is not a function
```

How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be public. Therefore add the public modifier before the variable

```
mapping (uint256 => uint256) public totalBoostedPercent;
```